# I am a graphic artist, am I allowed to create logos or products for Christians?

Tags: halal-haram

If, for example, I am asked to make a logo that says "Love Jesus": I am a Muslim and I love Jesus son of Mary, and so do they, but they do so in a manner that is not acceptable in Islam. Is it acceptable to create this logo?

Comment: Nous sommes un site anglophone; j'essaierai de traduire cette question pour vous, mais les reponses seront en anglais.

Answer (score -1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. If it was a I love Jesus shirt and it was for Muslim buyers only then it would be permissible. If you are selling it to Christians then we know their view Jesus (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) is wrong. So knowing that then you would part of their shirk. As Muslims we are commanded to stay away from even resembling non-Muslims in their beliefs and supporting them in their beliefs.

However, again if this is only for Muslims then there is nothing wrong with the shirt. If you change your niyyah and make this logo to help spread the deen of Islam by telling Christians through the shirt that we respect and love Prophet Jesus (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) that would be a great thing to do.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.